# Tables not recognized on restored geodjango postgis backup

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, database-backups

So I backed up my geodjango postgis database using `pg_dump` before performing some calculations which I've managed to mess up. I've created a new database using

```
createdb -T template0 -O proj proj_backup
psql proj_backup < proj_backup.pg
```

This seemed to work fine (though there were a few errors during the import), and connecting to the database using `psql` all my tables are there and appear to have the correct numbers of rows etc.

However, changing my settings.py to connect to my newly imported backup db (`proj_backup` in my example), gives me the following errors:

```
DatabaseError: relation "appname_model" does not exist
```

Any ideas? I'm guessing I did the dump wrong, or that I haven't maintained the ForeignKeys somehow. Thanks very much.

### Update

So I figured out my first mistake: I had two similarly named backup databases and connected to the wrong one. Connecting to the correct one seems to have fixed everything. However, it's still quite strange that it didn't recognize the tables in the other backup database, which definitely did exist. Running syncdb on the incorrect database ends up duplicating those tables (if I remember correctly, there were duplicate table names when I listed them all from within psql). Unfortunately, the way I discovered my mistake was by dropping the bad table to recreate it, and so in order to reproduce this error I'll probably have to use time machine. Still very strange, I'll give that a shot when I can get physical access to my work machine.

Answer (score 1):

So is your appname_model table there or is it a view?  Was it in public or another named schema?

If the table is there, then chances are you have it in a schema that is not in your database search path.  Check the search_path of your old database.  It might have included something other than the default, or your default search schema is set in postgresql.conf and is non-standard.

Comment: `appname_model` is a table and it did exist in the database. See my update though. Many thanks for the suggestion. I will try to test that when I can.